# how to detect what row was selected on swipe using MGSwipeTableCell library

Tags: ios, swift

before using MGSwipeTableCell library, i used the method editActionsForRowAtIndexPath to detect which row was selected and dynamically add UITableViewRowAction depending on the row information. 
but using MGSwipeTableCell how can this be done i.e. detect what row was selected before adding MGSwipeButton and not after clicking on it.

my current code is :

```
  in cellForRowAtIndexPath: 

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TaskListCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TaskListTableViewCell


                    cell.leftSwipeSettings.transition = MGSwipeTransition.Rotate3D
                    cell.rightSwipeSettings.transition = MGSwipeTransition.Rotate3D
                    cell.rightExpansion.fillOnTrigger = true;
                    cell.rightExpansion.buttonIndex = 0;

    var StatusButton = MGSwipeButton()
                    if(CurrentTaskStatus == "1")  // this is dependent on the row and is now returning wrong values because i don't have the index of the row. 
                  {
                        StatusButton = MGSwipeButton(title: NSLocalizedString("accept_task", comment: ""), backgroundColor: UIColor.redColor(), callback: {
                            (sender: MGSwipeTableCell!) -> Bool in


                            let indexx = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender)
                            let index = indexx?.row
                            self.CurrentTaskCode = self.TaskRowArrayList[index!].taskCode
                            self.CurrentTaskStatus = self.TaskRowArrayList[index!].taskStatus
                            self.CurrentTaskSubStatus = self.TaskRowArrayList[index!].taskSubStatus

// i need to get these before clicking the button and not after 

                            return true
                        })
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4**

Step 1.  Add the MGSwipeButton with its tag in right/left buttons array

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
            let cell  = tblPoolList.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PoolTableViewCell") as! PoolTableViewCell
            cell.delegate = self
            let btndelete = MGSwipeButton(title: "", icon: UIImage(named:"ic_delete_white_swipe_left"), backgroundColor: .red)
            btndelete.tag = indexPath.row
            let btnedit = MGSwipeButton(title: "", icon: UIImage(named:"ic_edit_white_swipe_left"), backgroundColor: .green)
            btnedit.tag = indexPath.row            
            cell.rightButtons = [btndelete,btnedit]
            cell.rightSwipeSettings.transition = .drag                        
            return cell       

    }
```

Step 2. you can easily get the index of table cell in its builtIn library methods.

```
func swipeTableCell(_ cell: MGSwipeTableCell, tappedButtonAt index: Int, direction: MGSwipeDirection, fromExpansion: Bool) -> Bool {

        print(cell.rightButtons.first!.tag)

        if index == 0 {
            print("Delete")
        } else {
            print(index)   
        }

        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The row selected during swipe should be the same as for the cell you are creating, so from your current code snippet you could simply use the `indexPath` parameter in the closure to the `MGSwipeButton` callback.

```
self.CurrentTaskCode = self.TaskRowArrayList[indexPath!].taskCode
self.CurrentTaskStatus = self.TaskRowArrayList[indexPath!].taskStatus
self.CurrentTaskSubStatus = self.TaskRowArrayList[indexPath!].taskSubStatus
```

If you can't do this, I would say you need to update with more info as to why, because that would be the obvious solution.

Comment: yes but if i place this before creating MGSwipeButton, then it won't be called on swipe because  the method cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called when swipe is made..

Comment: Try exchanging this for the code you had (at the same place) and see what happens. The indexPath variable will be closed over in the callback, meaning the value of it will be stored along with the closure for when it is needed (when swipes are made).